# shield ui chart disappeare when do a partial postback

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit, shieldui, partial-postback

The shield ui charts removed from HTML page once click on any button caused a partial post back in asp.net.

This problem happened after upgrading framework from 3.5 to 4.0.
There is no js error, and the control completly deleted from HTML once do a partial postback, and after page loading finished, the control appears again !

Comment: Might be hard for people to get an idea of what's happening without including any code in the question...